# Market Basket Analysis (Association Rule Mining) in Python doesn't resulting the Frequent Itemset

Tags: python, market-basket-analysis, mlxtend

I'm sorry for my bad english.

I have orders data called **df_merge** that has these columns :

> order_detail_id | order_id | product_id | price | quantity |  desc_product |  category |  base_price

[raw data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jfkjD.png)

I wanna do Association Mining with that data and I use this folowing code to pre-process the data :

```
list_merge = df_merge.groupby(['order_id'])['desc_product'].apply(list).values.tolist()

te = TransactionEncoder()
te_ary = te.fit(list_merge).transform(list_merge)
df = pd.DataFrame(te_ary, columns=te.columns_)
```

The code was run smoothly, but when i come to this code and use mlxtend package, i got nothing with the results of "frequent_itemsets" except the header.

> frequent_itemsets = fpgrowth(df, min_support=0.1, use_colnames=True)

I don't know what I did wrong..
Can anyone help me? Thank you.

Comment: Could you please provide some sample data that we can copy-paste to try it out?

Comment: Here are the sample data https://drive.google.com/file/d/1YorkkZji4vX9eEJLhf59tHoGtsrG8Lvs/view